# How to use an input field name stored as a string as php array indicies

Tags: php

I have an field name that is passed to me via an ajax function which i need to use to lookup values in an existing array. e.g.

```
$myarray = array(
    'name' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'first' => 'Steve'
        )
    ),
);


$incoming = 'name[0][first]';
```

So using the $incoming variable i wanted to get the corresponding data out of the array but cant figure out how to convert the string into the array indicies lookup.

Im trying to come up with a method that will work regardless of the level of nesting in the array.

Comment: `$incoming = $myarray['name'][0]['first']` and `$myarray["name"][0]["first"]` works as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Use a string as an array index path to retreive a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/php-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retreive-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion #1

Change the jQuery to send the request as JSON, which can instantly be converted into a PHP array with [json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

### Suggestion #2

If you can't switch to JSON, use [preg_split](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split the incoming field and loop over them to grab the correct array element. Something along the lines of:

```
$incoming = 'name[0][first]';

$parts = preg_split('/(\[|\])/', $incoming, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$el = $myarray;
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $el = $el[$part];
}

echo $el; // Steve
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work assuming there will always be 3 keys OR LESS. You could add "$keyX" vars and "if($numkeys == X)" for however big the array gets, but I could not find a more flexible fix

```
$incoming = 'name[0][first]';

$numkeys =  preg_match_all('/[\[]/', $incoming, $matches) + 1;

$split = preg_split('/[[\]]/', $incoming);
$key1 = $split[0];
$key2 = $split[1];
$key3 = $split[3];

if($numkeys == 1) {
echo $myarray[$key1];
} elseif ($numkeys == 2) {
echo $myarray[$key1][$key2];
} elseif ($numkeys == 3) {
echo $myarray[$key1][$key2][$key3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the eval function... evenhough this is extremely not recommended - especially when you get the string for the client (if I understood write)

```
 $incoming = 'name[0]["first"]';
 eval('$value = $'+$incoming+';');
 echo $value;
```

this script should print the data of the specific cell in the array...

again - this is not recommended unless you make sure that the input is in the format that you are expecting...

Comment: I don't think this should have been proposed, given the OP's level of knowledge of the subject. Even with the disclaimers.

Comment: With the information i gave the suggestion of running eval() against an argument passed via ajax would be a security disaster

Comment: I'm glad you understand that :)

Answer (score 0):

try using explode function here, in your example - name[0][first] will give give an array - of (name, 0] , first] ) as list/array after you explode on '['. Discard the first element and from the rest, take the ']' part out. Later you may convert them to respective formats - integers, strings etc.