# How can I access a multidimensional array element by path?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Use a string as an array index path to retreive a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/php-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retreive-a-value)

I have an array like so:

```
$array['image']['comment'] = 'something';
$array['image']['tag'] = 'happy';
$array['image']['colors']['blue'] = '12345';
```

If I have the path to each element in a string, how can I set or get the array value?

e.g where `$path = 'image/colors/blue';` the below function should return `12345`

```
function get_array($array, $path)
{
//what goes here?
}

function set_array($array, $path, $value)
{
//what goes here?
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to turn this multidimensional array into an object.?That would definitely make your life easier. This seems like a typical example of multi dimensional associative array abuse.

Comment: @thatidiotguy can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am saying that it looks like you are using a multidimensional array in a manner similar to how you would use an object. The advantage of using an object is better code maintainability. Functionally, everything works pretty similarly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$arr = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => array('c' => 'C', 'd' => array('e'=>'E')));

function read_array($array, $path)
{
  if($pos = strpos($path, '/') !== false){
    $key = substr($path, 0, $pos);
    $restOfKey = substr($path, $pos + 1); 
    return read_array($array[$key], $restOfKey);
  } else {
    $key = $path;
    return $array[$key];
  }
}

echo read_array($arr, 'a');      //A
echo read_array($arr, 'b/c');    //C
echo read_array($arr, 'b/d/e');  //E
```

You should of course add error checking and all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Very basic but it might provide you a jump off point:

```
$array['image']['comment'] = 'something';
$array['image']['tag'] = 'happy';
$array['image']['colors']['blue'] = '12345';

function get_array($array, $path) {
 if(strpos('/', $path) > 0) {
   list($first, $second, $third) = explode('/', $path);
   return $array[$first][$second][$third];
 }
}

get_array($array, 'image/colours/blue');
```

Comment: This actually needs some work, I've seen that you have seperate arrays. Let me edit..

Comment: yes - I guess so, it has to work dynamically but I could iterate over the result of the explode

Answer (score 0):

You could just call split or explode on the path string and insert the individual values into each dimension. This isn't unbounded, but i'm assuming you have a rough idea with this example of the depth this could go.

```
function getPathVal($array, $path) { 
    $path_array = explode("/", $path);
    $cnt = count($path_array);
    if ($cnt == 3) {
         return $array[$path_array[0]][$path_array[1]][$path_array[2]];
    } else if ($cnt == 2) {
          return $array[$path_array[0]][$path_array[1]];
    } else if ($cnt == 1) {
           return $array[$path_array[0]];
    } else {
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: no it has to work dynamically, hence the need for a function