# PHP edit value of multidimensional array item by path?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Access here
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

I also have the path to the value I want to edit (Access here), which looks like:

```
0,1,0,0
```

I want to change that value BY the known path. Of course I could access it with:

`$array[0][1][0][0] = 'My new value';`

But how do I automate this for an infinite depth?

Edit:

What I want, is to:

1. Pass the path of the value I want to edit (0,1,0,0)
2. Pass the array
3. Pass the new value

The function should change the value to a new one, based on the index path.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [How to use a string as an array index path to retrieve a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/php-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retreive-a-value)

That question has a answer that returns a value based on the path. But there is now way to edit said value.

Comment: What do you mean by automate? you want to add multiple values on that same path?

Comment: @RonakPatel He wants to access/manipulate the array by selecting indexes based on a string representation of the multiple dimensions.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. Could it be something like `editArray($myArray, '0100', 'My new value');`?

Comment: @Dennis - yes, just that, only the index path either an array or comma separated values.