# How to traverse into multi-leveled array to get value based on array of key names?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, traversal

Given the following array of key names in the following format (number of fields can change):

```
$field_names = Array
(
[0] => web
[1] => results
[2] => result
[3] => title
)
```

I'd like to access the 'content' key value of the following multi-leveled array:

```
$values=stdClass Object(
  [web] => Array(
    [results] => Array(
      [result] => Array(
        [title] => Array(
          [type] => default
          [content] => Sample content
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Sample example how value can be accessed given above arrays:

```
$value = $values->{$field_names[0]}[$field_names[1]][$field_names[2]][$field_names[3]]['content'];
```

For the sake of simplicity (keep it plain PHP), I won't get into much details as the existing code is part of some handler which is part of some plugin which is part of some [module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/yql_views_query/tree/handlers/yql_views_query_handler_field_column.inc#n18) which is part of another module which is part of content management system in order to parse YQL results, but its logic is broken.

The code looks like:

```
$field = array_shift($field_names);
$value = $values->$field;
foreach ($field_names as $field) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $value = $value[$field];
  }
}
```

I've tried to do a dirty patch like:

```
$value = is_string($value[$field]) ? $value[$field] : $value[$field]['content'];
```

And it worked for one example, but it doesn't work for all cases, like one above.

I'm aware of recursive functions and `array_walk_recursive()`, but I'd like to avoid headache of using them in order to make it simple as possible.

Is there any simple way of accessing value of multi-leveled array having dynamic array of key names?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/php-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retreive-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive solutions can also be simple

Your data:

```
$field_names = Array("web", "results","result","title");
$values->web["results"]["result"]["title"]=
            Array("type"=> "default", "content"=>"Sample content");
```

The function:

```
function getField($obj, $keys) {
    return ($key=array_shift($keys)) ? getField($obj[$key], $keys) : $obj["content"];
}

echo getField((Array)$values, $field_names);
```

But if you want a not recursive one, here it is:

```
$obj=(Array)$values;
while ($key=array_shift($field_names)) $obj=$obj[$key];
echo $obj['content'];
```

Comment: Tested recursive one-liner, really simple and works great, thanks. Posted patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2381533#comment-9642417).

Comment: Look at that @Adam .  You just helped a commit to Drupal!

Comment: If they don't give my name to the next version, I don't understand. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way, not recursive using a reference (taken from [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/use-a-string-of-values-or-an-array-to-navigate-an-array)):

```
function get($object, $path) {
    $prop = array_shift($path);
    $temp =& $object->$prop;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    return $temp;
}

$value = get($values, $field_names)['content']; //PHP 5.4.0
```