# Append to an array from a string

Tags: php, arrays, post

I've got an array, called $data which needs to be updated with data from an ajax call.

There are two variables sent via an ajax call (with example inputs):

**sectionDetails**:

```
[111][0][2][0][service_providers][]
```

**serviceProvider**:

```
Google
```

The serviceProvider is the data, and the sectionDetails is the array in which the serviceProvider should be in, in the $data array.

What I need is the $data array to end up as:

```
$data  =   Array
(
[111] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [service_providers] => Array 
                                                    (
                                                        [0] = Google
                                                    )
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

This way, I can dynamically input data into any cell and then later I can update specific arrays (e.g. `$data[111][0][2][0][service_providers][0]` = `"Yahoo"`;

The `$_POST['sectionDetails']` is however a string which is where the issue is.

Is there a way to change this string to an array that can then be appended to the main $data array (and in the case of an existing value in the same section, update the value)?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "$_POST['sectionDetails'] is however a string" - what does the string contain, exactly?

Comment: @dave `'[111][0][2][0][service_providers][]'` I think

Comment: Change your name attribute to `sectionDetails[]` and it is an array.

Comment: If you wanna call `$data[111][0][2][0][service_providers][0] = "Yahoo";` you do realize that you'll get to have an actual nested array, which the first node will have 112 positions right? It's ok if the previous positions, before the 111º where the others arrays are nested, have null values?

Comment: @AlanMachado that's not how PHP does arrays, you can have an array with a single element with index 111

Comment: @dave you're right, sorry. I'm working with 3 paradigms here, going nuts already.

Comment: This question is kind of similar to [How to use a string as an array index path to retrieve a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1677099/)

Comment: @dave , Alan is correct ; the string is [111][0][2][0][service_providers][]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a function like this:

```
function setToPath(&$data, $path, $value){
    //$temp will take us deeper into the nested path
    $temp = &$data;

    //notice this preg_split logic is specific to your path syntax
    $exploded = preg_split("/\]\[/", rtrim(ltrim($path,"["),"]")); 

    // Where $path = '[111][0][2][0][service_providers][]';
    // $exploded = 
    //    Array
    //    (
    //        [0] => 111
    //        [1] => 0
    //        [2] => 2
    //        [3] => 0
    //        [4] => service_providers
    //        [5] => 
    //    )
    foreach($exploded as $key) {
        if ($key != null) {
            $temp = &$temp[$key];
        } else if(!is_array($temp)) {
            //if there's no key, i.e. '[]' create a new array
            $temp = array();
        }
    }
    //if the last index was '[]', this means push into the array
    if($key == null) {
        array_push($temp,$value);
    } else {
        $temp = $value;
    }
    unset($temp);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
setToPath($data, $_POST['sectionDetails'], $_POST['serviceProvider']);
```

`print_r($data)` will return:

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_providers] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Google
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Aewsome! Can you comment your code a little? (The one with the function)

Comment: @AlanMachado hope that helps :) Please upvote if you approve!

Comment: Almost there! For some reason the array returned is the following, after adding 2 entires  : Array
    (
[0] => Array
 (
 [0] => Array
  (
  [339] => Array
   (
   [0] => Array
     (
    [2] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
      (
      [service_providers] => testing 2
       )
     )
    )
   )
  )

 [339] => Array
  (
  [0] => Array
   (
   [2] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
     (
      [service_providers] => testing 3
      )
      )
   )
  )
  )
)

Comment: Ignore the last comment. After testing it looks like the whole array being pushed on each update is not due to the function you provided. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @RehanAslam :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Being **very careful** and depending on the situation, you could use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval("\$data$sectionDetails = '$serviceProvider';");
```

`print_r($data)` will return:

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_providers] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Google
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

> **Caution**
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Had a quick test and this does seem to do the job, but as the input will be from various users, I rather avoid eval(). Thanks for the help!