# PHP Array Index using variable

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I'm having a trouble getting my array content when using a declared variable as my array indexes shown below.

[image]

```
$indexes = "[0][1][0][1]";
$code = $params["smv_code"].$indexes;
```

this returns an "Array to string conversion error";

Note that the $indexes is dynamic depends on the "parent_0_1_0_1" params content of the array index.

Comment: this is very unclear, what exactly are you trying to do, and what are thinking your code should be doing?

Comment: It is very clear what he wants to do - he is trying to navigate through the multi-dimensional array using code notation.

Comment: except he's not... what value is he actually looking for? the value of `parent_0_1_0_1` or the value of `$params['smv_code'][0][1][0][1]`

Comment: you're right... I didn't open the image... `parent_0_1_0_1` is an array itself with 0 => LVL2???

Comment: exactly making your answer irrelevant and this question nonsense as is

Comment: @PressingOnAlways the "parent_0_1_0_1" is just my indicator that that specific array has a parent located at index [0][1][0][1]. Your answer below solves it anyways thanks

Comment: It's weird and inefficient but... `$code = preg_match_all('/[^\[\]\d]/', $indexes) ? null : eval('echo $params["smv_code"]'.$indexes.';');`.. nvm, it's just for fun..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a string as an array index path to retrieve a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/how-to-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retrieve-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.` operator just does a [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) - it's not going to work for code like that. I don't think PHP has the ability to interpret raw code like that - at least not safely. (You can always use `eval`, but there are serious security concerns for using something like that - injection, etc.).

I would suggest just traversing the array "manually" through interpreting the indexes yourself. Change the `$indexes` to `"0,1,0,1"` and do the following:

```
$index_array = explode(',',$indexes)
$code = $params["smv_code"];
foreach($index_array as $i) {
  $code=$code[$i];
}
```

`$code` at the end should be the value you're looking for.

Comment: this solves my problem, just want to ask if it try to cast the params to (object) and make the $indexes "->0->1->0->1" and tried this one $params->smv_code{$indexes} will this be possible?

Comment: Nope, PHP isn't dynamic like that. Sorry. As mentioned before, the only way  (as far as I know) is to use the `eval()` function like Wizard posted in the comment... but then you can open yourself to exploits if they can craft the param properly to run other code.