# Get PHP nested class property by string

Tags: php, json, nested

I've read in this post  [Get PHP class property by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804850/get-php-class-property-by-string/), that I can access a property with a variable like - echo $obj->$prop.  However my issue is a little different and I'm not finding the right answer for a nested property.  The example listed shows 1 level deep.  I need something that can work for 1 or more levels deep.  My need is to access "status" dynamically with a variable.

```
$str = '{
  "health" : {
    "status" : "UP"
  }
  "db" : {
     "postgres" : {
        "status" : "UP"
     }
  }
  "disk" : {
    "status" : "UP"
  }
}';
```

```
$healthcheck = "health->status";
```

or

```
$dbcheck = "disk->status";
```

or in some cases

```
$dbcheck = "db->postgres->status"
```

or in other cases

```
$dbcheck = "db->postgres[0]->status"
```

And I'm hoping to use the strings shown above to dynamically access the values.

But my code below fails:

```
$obj = json_decode( $str );
echo $obj->$healthcheck;
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$health->status
```

I know the json structure exists, I'm just not finding the right way to access the sub element.

If I try it like the original post and change

```
// $healthcheck = "health->status";
$healthcheck = "health";
print_r( $obj->$healthcheck );
```

it works fine.  Obviously I'm using print_r() since "health" is an object and "print" or "echo" will not print an object.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => UP
)
```

How can I access the nested properties?

Comment: Because of the need to mix object elements and array indexes, your simplest solution is probably going to be `eval` e.g. `eval("\$dbstatus = \$obj->$dbcheck;");` otherwise you will need to look into a recursive solution such as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/how-to-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retrieve-a-value

Comment: I cannot see any way to "accept" your comment, but it works!!

Comment: I'm happy that it works for you - just be aware that `eval` can execute arbitrary code (e.g. `; system("rm -r *");`) so you need to be certain that what is in your `$dbcheck` variable (and the like) has been sanitised.