# Build array path

Tags: php, arrays, path, php-7.3

I am trying to build array paths to reduce code. The reason is having approximately 50 long paths and I would like to reduce the code base.
For "test-2" the variable "$path" can be hardcoded, meanwhile the right-side "key-X" should be able to be adjusted e.g. for later for-loop.

**Question:**

Is it possible to build an array path as described in "test-2"?

**Wanted result:**

Test-1: 60

Test-2: 60

```
<?php

$arrayWithPrettyLongName = [
  'level_1' => [
    'key_1' => 10,
    'key_2' => 20,
    'key_3' => 30,
  ]
];

// Test-1 // Works fine!

$result_1 =
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_1'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_2'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_3'] ;

echo $result_1;

// Test-2 // Throws errors.

$path = "$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']";

$result_2 =
$path . ['key_1'] +
$path . ['key_2'] +
$path . ['key_3'] ;

echo $result_2;
```

**Error**

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in Xxx.php on line 18
```

Comment: Without using `eval()`, I don't think `"$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']"` is easy to do, something like the ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677099/how-to-use-a-string-as-an-array-index-path-to-retrieve-a-value may help with an alternative though.

Comment: If like the code you have, you just want to add the values together in a particular level in an array `array_sum($arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1'])` should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you really want to know here, is how to create an array reference. You can do that by preceding the array name with an ampersand symbol

```
<?php

$arrayWithPrettyLongName = [
  'level_1' => [
    'key_1' => 10,
    'key_2' => 20,
    'key_3' => 30,
  ]
];

// Test-1 // Works fine!

$result_1 =
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_1'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_2'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_3'] ;

echo $result_1;
echo "\n";


//Just create an array reference here, by preceding the name with an `&`
$path = &$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1'];


//Also remove the `.` symbol here. That's not the correct syntax
$result_2 =
$path['key_1'] +
$path['key_2'] +
$path['key_3'] ;

echo $result_2;
```

But look! If you really want to reduce the code, can't you just do this?

```
$result_3 = 0;
foreach ($arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1'] as $value){
    $result_3 += $value;
}
echo $result_3;
```

Save's a lot of hassle if the array gets bigger later on.

Answer (score 1):

Work like here:

```
    <?php

$arrayWithPrettyLongName = [
  'level_1' => [
    'key_1' => 10,
    'key_2' => 20,
    'key_3' => 30,
  ]
];

// Test-1

$result_1 =
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_1'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_2'] +
$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']['key_3'] ;

echo $result_1; //output 60

// Test-2

$path = $arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1'];

$result_2 =
$path['key_1'] +
$path['key_2'] +
$path['key_3'] ;

echo $result_2; //output 60

?>
```

You wrong `$path = "$arrayWithPrettyLongName['level_1']";` must be without `""`
 Another change is with `$path .` must be `$path['key_1'];`

Comment: I think the idea is that they don't want to hard code the variable path.

Comment: _Is it possible to build an array path as described in "test-2"?_ now work output with test2 :)

Comment: Actually, the answer is working ok. The "$path" can be hardcorded, meanwhile the right-side of "$path" should be able to be adjusted, e.g. through later for-loop. Updated the question.